# Saving an install directory for software

Tags: java, linux, windows, installation

I have a software tool that I am working on in Java. It will be deployed to both Windows and Linux. I am at the phase where I am trying to determine the best course of action for saving the user's installation directory (where i will store all external files). Ideally I want the user to be able to move the program to any directory they choose (even after installation) and it will still be able to find the installation directory.

I have considered using environment variables to save the path but I am not sure if that is the best practice.

What is the standard practice for saving a path to an installation directory on Linux and Windows? (I am open to making different install logic for each OS)

**Edit**

After a bit more research, I have found that the /etc folder for linux is where I should store data and the Registry for windows. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: On Windows the path is often stored in the registry.

Comment: @Blobonat, i am aware that is usually the case but ideally I would like to keep things the same on both Linux/Windows. However if I have to add to the registry in windows and another location I believe I can still do that.

Comment: @Duck You can do a check to get the current OS and write to the appropriate installation directory based on that with: `System.getProperty("os.name")`

Comment: @SusannahPotts yes, I already have several OS-specific code segments, I am more concerned with *where* I should be reading/writing instead of how.

Comment: yes /etc/program-name is a standard place to store data in linux

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, registry works great.  Here's an example from a product I use (evo5.0 with eurovoiceHMP):
Locations of config and logging folders can be configured manually via the registry, 
eurovoiceHMP and evo5.0 then "find" these folders under registry: 
    HKLM/Software/eurovoice

Specific registry setting examples:
HKLM/Software/eurovoice/HMP:
    evoHMPLicencePath   C:\ProgramData\eurovoice\HMP\Config\Licences.txt
    InstallPath E:\hmpTest

HKLM/Software/eurovoice/evo50:
    evo50SystemVoiceFilesDir  C:\TeleSage\sysvox
    InstallPath     C:\Program Files\evo5.0
    evo50LogDir     C:\TeleSage\Logs